# Automatic email from wordpress in a specified time

Tags: php, wordpress, email, cron

I would like to send an automatic email from my wordpress site when my ssl certification validation is over. (I mean before 3 days to event)

I try to use the wordpress cron, but the email not send in the specified time.

What is the problem?

Thank you for help!

My code in the functions.php:

```
// create a scheduled event (if it does not exist already)
function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_six_hours'] = array(
        'interval' => 21600, // Every 6 hours
        'display'  => __( 'Every 6 hours' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

//Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_six_hours', 'myprefix_cron_hook' );
}

///Hook into that action that'll fire every six hours
 add_action( 'myprefix_cron_hook', 'myprefix_cron_function' );
```

My code in the php:

```
function displayHostsSection(){
$opts = get_option('sslMail');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Budapest'); // CDT
$send_date = date('Y.m.d', strtotime("+3 days"));
if (isset($opts['hosts'])) {
foreach($opts['hosts'] as $host => $date) {
$d = ($date instanceof DateTime) ? $date->format('Y.m.d') : 'Unknown';



function myprefix_cron_function() {

if($send_date  == $d){

$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "My Subject";
$txt = "My Text";
$headers = "From: $host " . "\r\n" .
"CC: ";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

};
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your `strtotime("+3 days")` put you 3 days into the future - shouldn't it be -3 days?

Comment: Why don't you just put an entry into your calendar manually after you installed a new cert? What's the point in checking constantly? Also, most cert providers will send you an email informing you about upcoming renewals.

Comment: @DaveCoast: Example: my ssl certification over time is 2017.11.20, and today is 2017.11.17. 2017.11.17 + 3 days = 2017.11.20
certification over time = today + 3days -> Send email.

Comment: @Gordon: I wouldn't like give my email address, because i wouldn't like receive spam.

Comment: If your cert provider spams you, you should change your cert provider. Or use a cert from http://letsencrypt.com and set it to autoupdate. In any case, the time you spent writing that code is better invested in a different solution.